# How to remove the absolute path appended to targets' name when open CMake projects with Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, building

I setup a CMake project, but when I open its folders with Visual Studio (not VSCode), Visual Studio added an absolute path to every target's name. How to remove them?

[image]

Part of the main CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(ZwHLR)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED 20)

add_compile_definitions(PROJECT_DIR="${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")

if (MSVC AND (MSVC_VERSION GREATER_EQUAL 1914))
    add_compile_options("/Zc:__cplusplus")
endif()

set(THIRD_PARTY_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ref")
set(THIRD_PARTY_EXTRA_DIR "${THIRD_PARTY_DIR}/extras")

# Windows Kits
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_KITS_10_DIR "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10")
set(CMAKE_VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION 10)
set(VCPKG_ENV_PASSTHROUGH "CMAKE_WINDOWS_KITS_10_DIR,CMAKE_VS_WINDOWS_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION")

set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

foreach(OUTPUTCONFIG ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES})
  string(TOUPPER ${OUTPUTCONFIG} OUTPUTCONFIG)
  set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUTCONFIG})
  set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUTCONFIG})
  set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${OUTPUTCONFIG} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUTCONFIG})
endforeach(OUTPUTCONFIG CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)

add_subdirectory(tools)
```

and tools/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(test_runner)
target_include_directories(
    test_runner PUBLIC
    ${ACIS_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/test_runner
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/phl_example
)
target_sources(
    test_runner PRIVATE
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/test_runner/main.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(
    test_runner PRIVATE
    CLI11 rapidjson ${HLR_LIBS} phl_example_object
)
target_link_directories(test_runner PUBLIC ${ACIS_LIBRARY_DIR})
set_target_properties(test_runner PROPERTIES VS_DEBUGGER_ENVIRONMENT "PATH=${ACIS_BINARY_DIR};$ENV{PATH}")
```

Comment: would this not be useful though? it includes the part of the path that indicates which build configuration it is (RelWithDebInfo), which would help disambiguate once you build multiple configurations.

Comment: @starball It's useful to me. If absolute path is contained in the target's name, I cannot upload my launch.vs.json to git to collaborate. Repos are cloned to different directories on different computers. Now I need to modify launch.vs.json every time.

Comment: what the heck is up with people setting `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` in their CMakeLists.txt files? this is the second time someone has made a post doing this recently... are you following some tutorial that does this? and why bother setting `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_<CONFIG>` manually? it'll be done automatically if needed https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html. is it supposed to increase similarity between multi and single-config generator directory structure?

Comment: where is `HLR_LIBS` defined? and the `phl_example_object` and `phl_example` targets?

Comment: @starball OK. At least for me they're for temporary use, not copied from some tutorial.
Other targets are hidden since they're not related to the question (also due to IP reasons). The whole project can be compiled right.

Comment: @NekomiyaKasane, why don't you use CMakeLists.txt for collaboration?